# Ansible: Invalid JSON when using --extra-vars

Tags: json, parsing, jenkins, ansible

### **Hi community,**

I have been struggling with an issue in ansible issue for days now.
Everything is executed wihtin a Jenkins pipeline.

The ansible command looks like:

```
sh """
        ansible-playbook ${env.WORKSPACE}/cost-optimization/ansible/manage_dynamo_db.yml \
        --extra-vars '{"projectNameDeployConfig":${projectNameDeployConfig},"numberOfReplicas":${numberOfReplicas},"dynamodbtask":${dynamodbtask}}'
    """
```

And the playbooks is:

```
playbook.yml

---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
      numberOfReplicas: "{{numberOfReplicas}}"
      dynamodbtask: "{{dynamodbtask}}"
      namespace: "{{projectNameDeployConfig}}"
      status: "{{status}}"

- tasks:
 - name: "Get replica number for the pods"
    command: aws dynamodb put-item --table-name pods_replicas
    register: getResult
    when: dynamodbtask == "get"

  - name: "Update replica number for specified pods"
    command: |
      aws dynamodb put-item 
      --table-name pods_replicas 
      --item '{"ProjectNameDeployConfig":{"S":{{namespace}}},"NumberReplicas":{"N":{{numberOfReplicas}}}}'
    register: updatePayload
    when: dynamodbtask == "put" and getResult is skipped
```

However, there is always the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["aws", "dynamodb", "put-item", "--table-name",
"pods_replicas", "--item", "{\"ProjectNameDeployConfig\":{\"S\":LERN-PolicyCenterV10},\"NumberReplicas\":
{\"N\":0}}"], "delta": "0:00:01.702107", "end": "2020-02-09 16:58:26.055579", 
"msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 255, "start": "2020-02-09 16:58:24.353472", "stderr": "\nError parsing parameter '--item': Invalid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded\nJSON received: {\"ProjectNameDeployConfig\":{\"S\":LERN-PolicyCenterV10},\"NumberReplicas\":{\"N\":0}}", "stderr_lines": ["", "Error parsing parameter '--item': Invalid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded", "JSON received: {\"ProjectNameDeployConfig\":{\"S\":LERN-PolicyCenterV10},\"NumberReplicas\":{\"N\":0}}"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Comment: What does your command line output when you execute the command: `aws dynamodb put-item --table-name pods_replicas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers to your question: the simple one and the correct one

The simple one is that had you actually fed the JSON into `jq`, or `python -m json.tool`, you would have observed that `namespace` is unquoted:

```js
    "{\"ProjectNameDeployConfig\":{\"S\":    LERN-PolicyCenterV10      },\"NumberReplicas\": {\"N\":0}}"
```

where I added a huge amount of space, but didn't otherwise alter the quotes

The correct answer is that you should never use jinja2 to try and assemble *structured* text when there are filters that do so for you.

What you *actually* want is to use the [`to_json` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data):

```
  - name: "Update replica number for specified pods"
    command: |
      aws dynamodb put-item 
      --table-name pods_replicas 
      --item {{ dynamodb_item | to_json | quote }}
    vars:
       dynamodb_item:
         "ProjectNameDeployConfig":
           "S": '{{ projectNameDeployConfig }}'
         "NumberReplicas":
           "N": 0
    register: updatePayload
    when: dynamodbtask == "put" and getResult is skipped
```

although you'll notice that I changed your variable name because `namespace` is the name of a type in jinja2, so you can either call it `ns` or I just used the interpolation value from your `vars:` block at the top of the playbook, as it doesn't appear that it changed from then

Comment: new error:
 FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["aws", "dynamodb", "put-item", "--table-name", "pods_replicas", "--item", "{\"ProjectNameDeployConfig\": {\"S\": \"LERN-policycenterv10-batch\"}, \"NumberReplicas\": {\"N\": 0}}"], "stderr": "\nParameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Item.NumberReplicas.N, value: 0, type: <type 'int'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>", "stderr_lines": ["", "Parameter validation failed:", "Invalid type for parameter Item.NumberReplicas.N, value: 0, type: <type 'int'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>"],..

Comment: You spent more characters typing that comment than you would by wrapping two quote markers around the **one integer** found in that whole block of text.

Comment: Ah, sorry. The 0 is substituted by ”{{numberOfReplicas}}” which is an integer.